# Enable button when started writing in TextArea using EXT JS

Tags: extjs

I have requirement to enable a button , lets say Submit button , when user will start writing in TextArea using EXT JS. 
At start, as TextArea is empty , Submit Button is disabled. As soo as user starts writing in TextArea , it should get enabled . 
Please tell me if there is any event which tracks writing in TextArea in EXT JS

Comment: You can listen to the change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do -

```
{
xtype     : 'textareafield',
grow      : true,
name      : 'MyTextField',
fieldLabel: 'MyTextField',
listeners : {
    blur: function(event, eOpts){
        // here you can get reference to the button and enable
    },
    change: function(newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        // this event will be fired whenever the value of the text field changes when you type.
        // You can even listen to this function and enable the button when this event fires
    }
}
```

}

To get a list of the events that you can listen to, I suggest you check the API doc. Here's the [TextArea api doc for Ext 5.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-event-change)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `formBind: true` will be enabled/disabled depending on the validity state of the form.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
        title      : 'Sample TextArea',
        width      : 400,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype     : 'textareafield',
            grow      : true,
            allowBlank: false,
            name      : 'message',
            fieldLabel: 'Message',
            anchor    : '100%'                
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'My Button',
            formBind: true,
            disabled: true
        }]
    });
```